# Appveyor out of heap space, Error C1060

Tags: c++, visual-c++, appveyor

I'm getting failed builds on Appveyor from running out of heap space: *Error C1060*

Trying to enable the 64-bit toolset as described here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s.aspx

by adding the following to the top of my build script:

```
- cd "\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC"
- .\vcvarsall.bat amd64
```

However, *vcvarsall* is unrecognized...

Any other suggestions to not run out of heap space? I also tried using the */Zm* option...

Answer (score 0):

This `- cmd: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64'` should work.

Side note:
We do not recommend changing current directory. But is you have to, please do `CD %APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER%` after that. This is not mandatory, but can save you from some unexpected behavior.

--ilya.